# Trying to display menu in textbox in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This a build up from previous questions, started from C# console now we're moving that same code into Visual studio Windows form application (using MVS 2010, its what the school gave us), I've decided to move the code one section at a time so as not to get confused and that way I can isolate the parts and possible problems. in console I had initialized a Dictionary with a list(class) that generated a small menu, I'm now trying to display said menu in a textbox. When i set the textbox to display the menu with `textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + STOCK.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ID {0} - Name: {1,-20} Price: {2:C2}", x.id, x.Name, x.Price)));`it say that `STOCK` doesn't exist. Here's the code so far:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var STOCK = new List<Items>
           {
            new Items{ id = 1, Name = "Bun", Price = 100},
            new Items{ id = 2, Name = "Soda", Price = 80},
            new Items{ id = 3, Name = "Cheese", Price =70},
            new Items{ id = 4, Name = "Tissue", Price = 50},
            new Items{ id = 5, Name = "Fabuloso", Price = 140},
            new Items{ id = 6, Name = "Grace Mackerel", Price = 90},
            new Items{ id = 7, Name = "Rice", Price = 50},
            new Items{ id = 8, Name = "Flour", Price = 40},
            new Items{ id = 9, Name = "Sugar", Price = 30},
           };



            var STOCKDict = STOCK.ToDictionary(i => i.id);

            var selecteditems = new List<Items>();

        }

        public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + STOCK.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ID {0} - Name: {1,-20} Price: {2:C2}", x.id, x.Name, x.Price)));
        }
        public class Items
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public decimal Price { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: STOCK is declared inside a method (Form_Load). In this way is a local variable that exists only inside that method and is destroyed when the code exits from that method. You need to declare it at the class level scope. But perhaps, if you are confused by this error message, it is better to read about Scopes and Visibility in C# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-domain

Comment: Also. _Console.WriteLine_ doesn't write in a Winforms Textbox. You need to append to the current Text [(TextBoxBase.AppendText)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare STOCK has a global level variable.

The variable you  created STOCK is inside the method, therefore its scope will end in form_load. If we create it in class level that is global level. It will present until the form is in use. 
Create it in class level as shown in the below code.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Items> STOCK = new List<Items>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           this.STOCK = new List<Items>
           {
            new Items{ id = 1, Name = "Bun", Price = 100},
            new Items{ id = 2, Name = "Soda", Price = 80},
            new Items{ id = 3, Name = "Cheese", Price =70},
            new Items{ id = 4, Name = "Tissue", Price = 50},
            new Items{ id = 5, Name = "Fabuloso", Price = 140},
            new Items{ id = 6, Name = "Grace Mackerel", Price = 90},
            new Items{ id = 7, Name = "Rice", Price = 50},
            new Items{ id = 8, Name = "Flour", Price = 40},
            new Items{ id = 9, Name = "Sugar", Price = 30},
           };



            var STOCKDict = STOCK.ToDictionary(i => i.id);

            var selecteditems = new List<Items>();

        }

        public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                STOCK.ForEach(x => strBuilder.Append(string.Format("ID {0} - Name: {1,-20} Price: {2:C2}", x.id, x.Name, x.Price)));
   textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text +  strBuilder.ToString();

        }
        public class Items
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public decimal Price { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

No need of console.WriteLine, Here the Console.WriteLine will write the data to output console window. Since you are moving from Console to win forms this statement is not needed. You can directly assign it to textbox. 
The change has been done in the above code.

PS: I have also used StringBuilder, instead of concatenating the textbox value for better memory usage.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, however i still have an error with the display `textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + STOCK.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ID {0} - Name: {1,-20} Price: {2:C2}", x.id, x.Name, x.Price)));` says it cannot convert type void to string

Comment: @Whitti1  did that help you or you are still facing issue ?

Comment: put a debugger and check what is happening in text_change event

Comment: Thanks, that worked out, guess now i need to edit the display but for now onto the rest of the code

Answer (score 1):

`STOCK` is a local variable in the scope of `Form1_Load` method. Therefore, you can't use it in another method.

One way to overcome this issue is to make the `STOCK` variable a class member. Then, you can access it from any method:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Items> STOCK;

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
        this.STOCK = new List<Items> { /* ... */ };
        // ...
    }

    public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // use this.STOCK here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things you can make better :

```
    public class Items
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
```

why do you need this is as Class , why not structure - > choose value types when you do not need any behavior

make the items an array instead of List , if you have know the number of items to be added in advance.

declare the items as global variable , preferably static readonly